# Calculate the area of $z=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}\;$ that is enclosed by $x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

The exercise is the text in the title. I'm studying surface integrals. To start I thougt to make a change to cartesian coordinates with $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$, that is, $z=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ . With this I make the following parameterization: $O(x,y)=[x/2,y,z=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}]$ Then I calculated the norm of the normal vector of $O(x,y)$ that is $(-x,\frac{-y}{2}, 1/2)$. 
Is it okay what I did? How did I continue the exercise?

Comment: I don't understand your approach. Moreover are you sure that you have written all the formulas correctly? Have you a final resul for this exercise?

Comment: @RobertZ What I did was parameterize trivially. My parameterization in principle was $L (x, y)=(x,y,(x^+y^)/2)$ but since the module of the vector product of the partial derivatives oficina L(x,y) did not allow me to use using the change in polar corrdinates x^2+(y^2)/2=r^2 in the integral of surface area I decided to use O(x,y) that does allow me to make this change to polar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition of [surface area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_scalar_fields) you have to evaluate
$$A=\iint_S\sqrt{1+f_x^2+f_y^2}dxdy=\iint_S\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}dxdy$$
where $z=f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ (a paraboloid) and 
$S=\{(x,y):x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}\leq 1\}$ (the interior of an ellipse).
After letting $X=x$, and $Y=y/2$ you should be able to use the polar coordinates. Unfortunately in the final result elliptic integrals are involved and there is no closed form.

Comment: What would the Jacobin module look like in this case? (when make the change to polar coordinates)

Comment: The integral does not have a closed form. Are you sure that the statement of the problem is correct? What is the source of this exercise. Have a result?

Comment: I see. It is an exercise of a mathematical analysis II practice of the University of Buenos Aires

Comment: OK. If we replace $x^2+y^2/4=1$ with $x^2+y^2=1$ then  the result is $-(2/3)\pi+(4/3)\sqrt{2}\pi$.